# onPostExecute called only when call to another void is not present

Tags: android, android-asynctask, void

I have the following `onPostExecute` code for an `AsyncTask`. It runs fine as is. However, when I remove the commented bit of code, I never receive the `onPostExecute` event (No Toast).

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      internetData = result;        
      tempview.append(result + "\n");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), internetData.toString(), 1).show();
      //setServiceId();
}
```

The `setServiceId` event and follow on events are (URL deleted on purpose), `GetXMLData` is my `AsyncTask`:

```
public void setServiceId() {
    if (internetData != null) {
        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(internetData));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    serviceId = xpp.getText();
                    serviceHistory = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/history";
                    serviceUsage = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/usage";
                    serviceDetails = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/service";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serviceId, 1).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    updateHistory();
    updateDetails();
    updateUsage();
}

public void updateHistory() { //Never called
    new GetXMLData().execute(serviceHistory);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update History", 1).show();
}

public void updateUsage() { //Never called
    new GetXMLData().execute(serviceUsage);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Usage", 1).show();
}

public void updateDetails() { //Never called
    new GetXMLData().execute(serviceDetails);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Details", 1).show();
}

    public void updateData() { //First call
    new GetXMLData().execute(serviceListing);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Data", 1).show();
}
```

The last event above, `updateData` is called, and the `Toast` never seems to disappear when the `setServiceId` event isn't commented out. As well as this, the XML data is not retrieved.

When it is commented out, I receive the XML data for the `updateData()` event, but no following events, and I do not get the `Toast` from `onPostExecute`. Any suggestions as to why this is occuring?

Comment: `while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)` loops for infinity if `eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT`. You need to change eventType inside the cycle.

Comment: +1 for the above comment. use xpp.getNextTag() or xpp.getNext() within that while loop.

Comment: @andrew_pako You sir, are correct...I feel so silly :D

Comment: @andrew_pako if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing XML parsing in `onPostExecute()` as this method runs on the UI thread. Your XML parsing should be done in `doInBackground()` and you should just be updating the UI in `onPostExecute()`. That isn't the cause of your problem, but it will help your app feel much more responsive if you keep heavy XML parsing operations off the UI thread.

Comment: @MarkAllison this xml parsing is not large at all. Its about 4 lines of short XML. However, I will take the rest of your advice and put the larger XML parsing in a background task.

Comment: @Asryael it doesn't matter. Creating and running an XML parser is a heavy operation. You should never do it on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a mistake in your while loop condition, that will loop for infinity and make your app to hang:

```
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            serviceId = xpp.getText();
            serviceHistory = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/history";
            serviceUsage = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/usage";
            serviceDetails = "www.google.com/" + serviceId + "/service";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serviceId, 1).show();
        }
    }
```

Add next line within your loop:

```
    eventType = xpp.next();
```